# Facing issue with showing pins / clusters : OCMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

In my app I have `MKMapView` which works well, then I have replaced `MKMapView` with `OCMapView` and pins stopped being displayed. and I found `viewForAnnotation` function stopped being called. Only thing I found different from sample project is method for adding annotation, in sample project `addAnnotations` method is used but in my case I have to use `addAnnotation` method in loop.

Any idea what I am missing or any workaround to call `viewForAnnotation` and start displaying pins.

source : https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView

Answer (score 1):

***We really don't need 3rd party library for Clustering*** I guess, 
when in iOS MKMapView is already providing a method:-

### (NSSet *)annotationsInMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect

What a programmer should do is-- One map will be presented in the view controller which will be used find the coordinate but the map-view will be hidden and another map-view will be responsible for displaying the annotation.

A demo Code is already there in Apple Developer website:-

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoMap/Introduction/Intro.html